# scikit - GridSearchCV on CalibratedCV with RandomForrestClassifier as base estimator

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, grid-search, hyperparameters

I was wondering if there is a way to perform GridSearchCV on a RandomForrestClassifier embedded in CalibratedCV, I would like to optimize for log loss so I need the evaluation to happen on CalibratedCV but I would like to change the params of RandomForrest.

Thanks in advance

Comment: From the documentation I do not see a way to pass the base estimator to CalibratedCV within a Pipeline so I would have to implement a custom classifier which is not trivial because it would have to work with the clone() method used in GridSearchCV.

Answer (score 0):

Since I needed RandomSearchCV and RandomForrestClassifier can happily use all available cores I ended up with my own solution that uses:

```
from numpy import random
def random_params(model_parameters):
    model_params = {}
    for k, v in model_parameters.iteritems():
        if type(v) is list:
            model_params[k] = random.choice(v)
        elif 'scipy' in str(type(v)):
            try:
                from scipy.stats import distributions
            except ValueError:
                raise ValueError('random_search requires scipy.stats')

            model_params[k] = v.rvs(1)[0]
        elif isinstance(v, int) or isinstance(v, float) or isinstance(v, str):
            model_params[k] = v
        else:
            raise ValueError('Unrecognized search value for parameter %s' % k)
    return model_params
```

to draw parameter sets at random. The rest is trivial.